# How can I get the length of a javaFX audio clip in millis

Tags: audio, javafx, duration

Hi everyone I want to play a JavaFX audio clip and sleep the time that it takes this audio clip to finish. I can't find any method in the JavaFX AudioClip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `AudioClip` is not meant for such things, maybe playing a "real" [`Media`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html) is better suited in this case.

You can try this (not very elegant) approach: just sleep and check every now and then whether the clip is still playing:

```
AudioClip sound = new AudioClip("mySound.wav");
sound.play();

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (sound.isPlaying())
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

System.out.println("Played for " + (duration / 1000) + "seconds.");
```

You could also try to create a `Media` object from your source just to get the duration. Then, play it as `AudioClip` and use the duration of the `Media` to sleep. This requires initializing a proper FX environment, though:

```
AudioClip sound = new AudioClip("mySound.wav");
sound.play();
Thread.sleep((long) new Media("mySound.wav").getDuration().toMillis());
```

Comment: When I try to get the duration I get Nan

Comment: @Michael I don't have enough experience with fx media to diagnose that. Maybe you can ask a new question.

Comment: ok thank you very much